# Structural Equation Model

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

It is  possible to include observed variables as part of the structural model. For example, to find the impact of latent variables on observed variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

With older programs, such as LISREL you couldn't do this - you had to create a latent with a single indicator, and no error variance. Now you just do it, for e.g. in Mplus, if F is latent and x is observed, you'd write

```
x on f;
```

In Lavaan, you'd write:

```
x ~ F
```

Also, when you have a latent variable, with indicators, the loading is equivalent to the regression. So (in Mplus):

```
F by x;
```

is exactly the same as my first statement.

Comment: I used the maximum likelihood estimates (MLE) approach for the determination of SEM, which was carried out in AMOS version 20.

Comment: You can do it in AMOS too. Just draw an arrow from the latent to the manifest variable. (One of the [several] reasons I don't like AMOS is that I can't write the code which tells you want to do, and you can't tell me what you did. It's much easier to help people if you use any other program.)